# Finding and removing all occurences of shortcode with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, shortcode

I have this shortcode for wordpress.

```
[shortcodename code="dhgsfy87djh" time="2"][/shortcodename]
```

This pattern may appear more than once inside a textarea. I need to remove all occurrences of this pattern in the text area. The problem is - I am not a reg ex person. Kindly suggest a regex in to remove all occurrences of this pattern using javasript.

For example the content may be like this:

```
[shortcodename code="dhgsfy87djh" time="2"][/shortcodename] [shortcodename code="hdfds8f7684768" time="5"][/shortcodename] blah blah [shortcodename code="df87s8bdf78sd" time="8"][/shortcodename]
```

![This how it is][1]

http://s9.postimg.org/em9myvz1r/snap.png

Since i really dont know why this question was down voted, i am assuming someone here was einstien and i am definitely not competing.

So please look at the picture again. say this is the wordpress comment box. Now i need only one occurrence of shortcode to be in there.That too in the beginning only.  Say some one copy pastes more of it here and there i want that stripped off. And then i would add only one on the top.

the adding part i am doing, but the stripping i dont know. I used some reg ex but it works in php preg_match however it does not work in javascript.

This is what i used.

/(^[shortcodename[]).([ ]*).(code=\"someprefix_).([A-Za-z0-9]+).([ ]*).(time=\"(\d*)\"*).(]*).([/shortcodename])/i;

This is the first question of mine being answered on stackoverflow, so i request everyone for little patience with me. Dont down vote if you dont know the answer, say "i dont know" or "i didnt understand" or "provide more info".

Now please help me with this.

Comment: You can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/. Try some regex, then come back with the code and a live demo to reproduce the problem. Regex are scary at first, but they're not too hard to learn. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\[[^\[]*shortcodename[^\]]*\]/ig`

Should work for you. This is assuming of course that your wrapping pattern is the same.

The /i flag will allow for case-insensitive matches, and the /g flag will ensure all matches are replaced.

**Note:** this will also remove the content *inside* the shortcode wrapper.

You can see a working example here: regex101.com/r/tB5nG2

**Edit**: given the nature of your question, I suspect that there's much more to what you're trying to match than simply the examples you gave. Try giving broader examples and we can enhance our respective answers.

Comment: Hi i have added more data, please see if this helps.

Comment: Your regex didnt work for me as expected. For the data:
[shortcodename code="dhgsfy87djh" time="2"][/shortcodename] blah blah [shortcodename code="df87s8bdf78sd" time="8"][/shortcodename]

it game one match which was the whole content. even though there are 2 distinct shortcode patterns it included everything.Note that the content of shortcodes are null. Still your regex picked up content outside the shortcode as well.

Comment: OK, give me a minute to see what I can do.

Comment: Little confused here, i did:

$pattern = "/\[[^\[]*shortcodename[^\]]*\]/";
$teststr = '[shortcodename code="529a9c6e3b085" time="2"][/shortcodename] blah blah [shortcodename code="529a9c6e3b085" time="2"][/shortcodename]';

var matches = $teststr.match($pattern);
alert(matches);

And what i get is : null

Comment: Even tried this still nothing..

$pattern = "\[[^\[]*shortcode[^\]]*\]";
$pattern_regex = new RegExp($pattern);
$teststr = "[shortcode code=\"529aa3f920f2b\" time=\"3\"][/shortcode] blah blah [shortcode code=\"529aa3f920f2b\" time=\"3\"][/shortcode]";
if ($teststr.match($pattern_regex)) {
alert("Successful match");
}

Am i doing it wrong ??

Comment: Anways I manages to get it working for me. Thanks a ton and I hope this question is upvoted now.

Comment: Hey! Fantastic news -- sorry I missed your earlier comments.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
text.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will make sure only remove the matched [tag][/tag], but not [a]cc[/b]

```
text = text.replace(/\[(\S+)[^\]]*][^\[]*\[\/\1\]/g, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2ZVk/1/

Comment: This works as described, but many Wordpress shortcodes don't have an end tag, like this `[button title="foo"]`